# Organize a C++ solution shared by eclipse and msvc

Tags: c++, visual-c++, eclipse-cdt

I know this subject could be somehow subjective but I need some ideas.
I'm trying to reorganize my game engine code. The project is divided in modules (core, Log, ...) and for each module (or project) I have another project with unit tests. This helps reusability, because I can take Log project and their test and put in another project. I don't want a large 'src' folder with thousand files.

I want to work in eclipse and msvc and I don't have problem working with vitual file structures if it helps to maintain the same (or similar) structure in eclipse and msvc.

Thanks!!

Comment: Have you considered or tested cmake with Visual c++/Eclipse CDT generators?

Comment: I also vouch for cmake, I'm using that for my own game since it is crossplatform. That also automatically implies the need for different toolsets and that is satisfied quite well with cmake.

Comment: I have played a little with CMake and I find little obscure when you need to inject some flags. I also don't like the projects it inserts into msvc. Maybe is time to give it another run, but I'd love to have another alternative

Answer (score 1):

If you are using different IDE for the same project or if you want to share modules, I suggest to use [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/) to generate project files for both msvc and eclipse from a single source/project structure.